# Ordering of elements in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Following is my code which is working fine in terms of UI. Though the problem is my **buttons are dynamic** (it should be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc in numbers) so It should be `Button 1, Button 2, Button 3, Button 4` and not `Button 4, Button 3, Button 2, Button 1`. Let me know how can I manage this using flexbox.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.title-container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
}
.action-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
button:first-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>
      Heading Title
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="action-container">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT -**

I know `flex-direction: row` will make the elements to make appear in correct position but I want last element to stick at the last so that's why I choose `flex-direction: row-reverse` ..but this thing will change the ordering then as well.

Comment: Dynamic code which generates buttons could generate them in reverse order, than ordering would be as expected and last button will "stick" to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) for the correct alignment. I've added a few comments in the code.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
}

.action-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* Changed */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* Added */
}
/*
  Add margin to each button except for the first one
*/
button:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>
      Heading Title
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="action-container">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `flex-direction: row` instead of `flex-direction: row-reverse` on .`action-container`:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
}

.action-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button:first-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>
      Heading Title
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="action-container">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will make my Button to start from the left of the container(blue container)  though I want last element to remain stick to the right. That's I choose row-reverse to start items to start from right only..but its reversing the order which is expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `order` CSS attribute to manually set the order of the flexbox elements. Also, after setting the order you might need to set the `margin-left` property of the buttons instead of `margin-right` if you want the last button to stick to the end. Below is a working example -

```css
.container {
border: 2px solid red;
display: flex;
width: 100%;
}

.title-container {
border: 1px solid green;
flex: 1;
}

.action-container {
border: 1px solid blue;
flex: 1;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

button {
margin-left: 10px;
}

button:first-child {
margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title-container">
    <h3>
      Heading Title
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="action-container">
    <button style="order: 4">Button 1</button>
    <button style="order: 3">Button 2</button>
    <button style="order: 2">Button 3</button>
    <button style="order: 1">Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```